# Can swapping objects of fundamental types throw?

Tags: c++, pointers, exception, swap

Is swapping of objects of fundamental types (integers, chars, bools, pointers, ...) with `std::swap` guaranteed by the Standard not to throw an exception? I guess this question must have been asked before, but I cannot Google any such one.

I am aware of the definition of `std::is_nothrow_swappable`, but then, I don't know whether fundamental types are *NothrowConstructible* and *NotrhowAssignable* as well.

*(I am specially interested in swapping of pointers.)*

Comment: How swapping objects of fundamental types could throw an exception?

Comment: I am not aware of any explicit guarantee in the Standard that fundamental types swapping is noexcept. Having said that, I believe, you are overthinking it. I am yet to see a platform where that would not be the case.

Comment: Great question. Impossible to answer without controversy and some level of assumption about the aims of the language. :)

Answer (score -2):

[For pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap#Exceptions), the method specifies `noexpect`.
For non-pointers it is `noexpect` if the value is [`is_nothrow_move_constructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_move_constructible) and [`is_nothrow_move_assignable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_move_assignable) which is true for 'fundamental' types (aka. primitives, e.g. int, float, char).

Comment: It specifies `noexcept`.

Comment: Where is that specialization/overload for pointers defined? I don't see it in the linked page you provided. I see only overloads for arrays.

Comment: there is no overload for pointers. just the overload for arrays is noexcept if swapping pointers is noexcept, but nowhere on the page there is a statement wether swapping pointers is noexecpt

Answer (score -2):

> Is swapping of objects of fundamental types (integers, chars, bools, pointers, ...) with std::swap guaranteed by the Standard not to throw an exception?

Yes

#### Documentation:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap

see note 1:

> Swaps the values a and b. This overload does not participate in overload resolution unless `std::is_move_constructible_v<T>` && `std::is_move_assignable_v<T>` is true

Following the documentation down the rabbit hole, we know that intrinsic types are trvially_nothrow_constructible. Pointers are intrinsic types.

Therefore, guaranteed.

#### Layman's reasoning:

If swapping of fundamental types is not `nothrow`, then nothing can be. Since all types are composed, directly or indirectly, of fundamental types.

#### Results of comments and downvotes:

While it is true that the standard does not contain any explicit requirement that the assignment of a *fundamental type* will not throw, neither does say that there is a possibility of the assignment of a fundamental type can result in an exception being thrown.

Indeed, [expr.throw] indicates only one means of throwing an exception - executing a *throw-expression*.

My reading of the meaning of the term "Fundamental Type" implies a type which is represented by a byte pattern and nothing more. It seems highly illogical to me that the movement of mere bytes at the CPU level will result in a high-level operation such a c++ exception being thrown.

However, I must conceed, whether self-evident or not, that nowhere in the standard does it *actually say* that assigning a pointer to a pointer will not result in an exception.

Nevertheless, I'll be a monkey's uncle if it does. :)

Comment: Could you please add a quote from the Standard? Or is this axiomatic?

Comment: A simple 'Yes' is certainly not an answer enough for such a question.

Comment: @SergeyA The question didn't ask for elaboration.

Comment: Still an answer like that is, at most, comment.

Comment: Still not good enough. This point was already taken in the question itself. Where does it say that `intrinsic types are trvially_nothrow_constructible`?

Comment: @SergeyA hmm. interesting. The standard does not, as I recall, allow for the throwing of exceptions resulting from the assignment of fundamental types. What exception would be thrown?

Comment: I do not know, this is why I didn't post the answer. But OP asks for standard guarantee, and unless you can find one, I can't accept this as an answer.

Comment: @SergeyA OK. The standard says that an exception is thrown by `throw`. It does not say that fundamental type can invoke an exception during copy/assignment. It does say that copying the underlying bytes from one fundamental to another copies the value and cites `std::memcpy` as an example. Amusingly, `std::memcpy` is not marked `nothrow` but it's a wrapper of C's `memcpy` which is intrinsically `nothrow`.
Perhaps necessity of fundamental types not throwing was self-evident to the standard's authors. But you are correct. There is no explicit guarantee that fundamental types will not throw. :)

Comment: @RichardHodges while I still won't upvote it :), I won't downvote the answer in it's current form either.

Comment: @SergeyA gracious of you :) I think in fairness, the fact that only a throw statement can cause an exception is enough. Fundamental types are not classes. There cannot be any code in their constructors or destructors, because such functions do not exist. Therefore they cannot throw exceptions. However, it might be worth a question in the std.discussions mailing list.